# Firebase rule on reading data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a 2 object "franchises" and "salon" I want to give user right to only read the data if franchises "salon_id" exists in the salon object uid.

My data looks like this - [image]

My rule looks like this -

```
{
 "rules": {
  "franchises": 
  {
    "$uid":
    {
      ".read":"$uid == root.child('salon').uid",
      ".write":false
    }
  }
 }
}
```

As I can see when I try to save the rule it giving an error in this line -

> ".read":"$uid == root.child('salon').uid".
>
> Error saving rules - Line 7: No such method/property 'uid'.

Comment: Might be use " === " instead of  " == ".

Comment: No same thing added the error that i am getting.